# Does the iCloud retain data for a period after the user specifies to delete it?

Tags: icloud, data, macos, time

Does deleting iCloud backups delete the associated data immediately or does Apple retain the data for a period of time?

Comment: I would say not on purpose (not planned) , it will do it as soon as possible.

Comment: I would guess that the data would stay on Apples servers for a few months before it was completely purged.
I'm wiling to bet that once your data is uploaded, it's sent to 12 different data centers world wide. In the event that one of those data centers goes down your data is retained. But if you delete it, it takes a while for that 'delete' to propagate through all their servers.

Comment: That seems plausible, I was thinking more along the lines of legal precautions. Holding data for a set amount of time after the initiated deletion for law enforcement agencies, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter I think whether backup is deleted immediately or schedule for being removed after some delay. The more important for you is, that once you hit "Delete" it disappears and releases used space on your account. I know that probably you have security concerns but in this case I would trust Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there would be a time frame to which the data would be able to be retained given some simple knowledge of server configurations.

You could think of the iCloud server as a series of hard drives all connected together and connected to the Internet. Some of the hard drive are used for saving your information and your iCloud account allows you to choose how big you want your iCloud storage capacity to be.

Other hard drives are used to backup those hard drives. These would be used in the case a large number of the hard drives were not working properly. In this case your information is still saved, which is a very smart and good business practice.

Some other hard drives are used when only one of the hard drives with customer information is failing, then this drive will pickup where it left off so there are no service issues. Also, very smart practice.

So as far as that information which has been deleted, it is probably still able to be retained for a period of time, after which it would be overwritten on the drives which backup the drives with the original data. Your privacy would still be respected due to the high encryption level of iCloud.

Lastly, retaining the information through an interface such as the Settings>iCloud pane in iOS would not be available. However, the information may still be able to be retained in the case it were done on accident.

Answer (score 0):

Only the people that wrote the code that makes up iCloud will know for sure. If you trust the company, then no, they won't retain it, not knowingly at least.